# Cutoff for conditional independence from inverse covariance

Tags: correlation, causality

I have several covariates of mixed data types (e.g. continuous and binary).
I am trying to determine covariate pairs that are conditionally independent of all the other covariates by checking the covariance matrix (`np.linalg.inv()`).
The thing is that many covariate pairs have the inverse covariance value that are very close to 0.
I'd like to set up a cutoff to call conditional independence.

Do you know any way to set up the cutoff?
One way I can think of is by estimating p-value, but `np.linalg.inv()` does not directly give that.
Please also let me know if you know a function that calculates the inverse covariance value with p-value.

Comment: I'm a little confused.... why are you using `np.linalg.inv` and expecting a p-value? `inv` inverts a matrix, it doesn't do any statistics test. Maybe take a look at scipy's statistical tests to see if you can use these (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/stats.html#statistical-tests).

Comment: You're right that I can't use np.linalg.inv and expect to get p value. I just wanted to find an alternative function that can calculate this value and estimate statistical significance. For example, I know pcorr in R can do just that. But then, it takes too much time to run for all the pairs.